# Correlate Wireshark's timestamp with ::QueryPerformanceCounter return value

Tags: c++, winapi, network-programming, wireshark

I am trying to determine how long it takes for a network packet takes to travel from Wireshark (which I presume is pretty close to the hardware) to the point in my code at which I call ::QueryPerformanceCounter.  I am capturing in Wireshark its timestamp for the packet arriving, but I don't know how to compare that to the value that is returned by ::QueryPerformanceCounter.

Comment: The performance counters are just an ever increasing counter, and can't be connected to a timestamp.

Comment: That is perhaps true, but WinPcap (the library underlying Wireshark) uses QueryPerformanceCounter to determine its timestamps so there must be a way to combine the result from QPC with another value to compare.

Comment: Perhaps you could take a look at WinPcap's source code to see what exactly it does to get the timestamp, and do the the same?

Answer (score 0):

You can call QueryPerformanceFrequency to get the number of counts per second. This means that if you have two count readings, one when Wireshark receives the packet, and a second when the packet reaches your code, you can subtract them to get a number of counts, and then use the frequency to get a time duration. However, the raw value of the counter has no meaning- it only has meaning when compared to another reading of that counter.

Comment: CPU clock frequency can change, so it's not reliable to use it for a long period of time.

Comment: Thanks.  I don't think I can get access to Wireshark/WinPcap's value for QueryPerformanceCounter.  The timestamp it appears to put out is the number of seconds since 1970, followed by a sub-second value calculated via a QueryPerformanceCounter difference.  I will have to have a think whether I can calculate the same value in my code.